# Showing image inside hexagon with html5 and kineticjs

Tags: image, html, kineticjs

I want to draw a hexagon and show an image inside that using html5.
I have tried it out but I am not getting image as the result.
I want to use [kineticjs](http://kineticjs.com/) only for this.

Here is the code:

```
function hexagon(){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: "container"
    });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      sides: 6,
      radius: 100,
      fill: {image: "css/images/logo.png"},

      stroke: "royalblue",
      strokeWidth: 2
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(hexagon);
   // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution.

Posting it late (better late than never)

It should be:

```
fill: {image: "css/images/logo.png", offset: [0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

fill takes an image object.  Try the following:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

logo = new Image();
logo.src = "css/images/logo.png";

var hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      sides: 6,
      radius: 100,
      fill: {image: logo},

      stroke: "royalblue",
      strokeWidth: 2
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(hexagon);
   // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
}
```

Comment: It is not working. I also tried putting object of kineticimage. but still it is not working.

Comment: Does the debug console tell you anything useful?

Comment: No, I just get a black color filled hexagon instead of the image inside hexagon. What to do?

Comment: Does the debug console tell you anything?

Comment: I have got the solution. It should be:

fill: {
            image: logo,
            offset: [0, 0]
       }

Answer (score 0):

The author of KinectJS has written some really great tutorials. In this one he draws an image in a pentagon, as well as a few other things. Should be enough to help you.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-set-fill-with-kineticjs/